# Фиксированная разметка в html и css

Tags: html, css

Помогите пожалуйста! Все свое содержимое и элементы в html заключил внутри элемента div с идентификатором allcontent в область фиксированной  ширины, равную 1000 пикселям. По неведомым мне причинам не срабатывает гибкая разметка в мобильном телефоне margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;  Хотя в справочнике написано что должно работать на ура, но не получается!

```
<body>
<div id="allcontent">
<div id="avt">
<a href=""><img src="img/avto.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="">О компаний</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Производство</a></li>
<li><a href="">Для партнеров</a></li>

<li><a href="">Для клиентов</a></li>
<li><a href="">История компаний</a></li>

<li><a  href="">Для клиентов</a></li>
<li><a  href="">История компаний</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="">Продукт компании</a>
<ul>
 <li><a href="">Шины</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Машинное масло</a></li>

 <li><a href="">Кондиционеры</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Диски</a></li>

 <li><a href="">Зеркала</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Запчасти</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="">Наши Услуги</a>
<ul>
 <li><a href="">Балансировка</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Мойка</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Тех.проверка</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Ремонт Двигателя</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Кузовной ремонт</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Замена Шин</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="">Информация и телефоны</a></li> 
<li><a href="">Фотогалерея</a></li>
<li><a href="">Заказать услугу</a></li> 
<li><a href="">Как проехать к нам</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="photo">
<a href=""><img  src="img/img7.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<div class="photo-title">
<p><a href="">Продукт компании</a></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="photo">
<a href=""><img  src="img/img8.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<div class="photo-title">
<p><a href="">Наши Услуги</a></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="photo">
<a href=""><img src="img/img9.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<div class="photo-title">
<p><a href="">Информация о нас</a></p>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можно поподробней пжлста, с примером разметки и описанием задачи.

Comment: При входе на сайт через мобильный телефон не отрабатываться гибкая разметка. Все содержимое прилипает к правой стороне браузера!

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под областью фиксированной ширины, о какой области идет речь ?

Comment: #allcontent{ width: 1000px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
Все браузеры на компах отрабатывают этот css селектор нормально. Все содержимое отображается по центру. Но при попытке выйти через моб. тел. все содержимое отображается  с правой стороны  моб.браузера.

Comment: На мобильном телефоне какое разрешение экрана и браузер ?

Comment: 960 x 640, Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получается, что ширина в пикселях вашего экрана 640(это очень приблизительная цифра, там есть ньюансы). Ваш контейнер 1000px. Вывод: ваш контейнер на уровне логики не может находиться по середине.

Если на мониторе вы хотите контент в блоке по середине, а на телефоне контент, который не будет у краев экрана, и не желаете запариваться на адаптивную верстку, можно попробовать как то так:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="content">
        содержимое
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    #container {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .content {
        padding: 30px;
    }
</style>
```

Это очень простое тупое решение. Хотите круче, нужно будет почитать про media queries.

Comment: спасибо! Вроде дело с двинулось с мертвой точки! Есть в какую сторону копать:) Я имею ввиду "media queries".

Comment: @Arty21 Про media queries можете здесь http://designnotfound.ru/about-media-queries/ и здесь http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieru/archive/2011/01/25/the-css-corner-css3-media-queries.aspx почитать